# Typo3 - TypoScript show page content and not TypoScript String

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

How do I let my typo3 Template show my page content?
Content:
[image]

Template Setup config:
[image]

I've read the typo3 documentation everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described in the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-typoscript-in-45-minutes/11.5/en-us/ReadingContentRecords/#reading-content-records).

```
page.10 = CONTENT
page.10.table = tt_content
page.10.select {

   # "sorting" is a column from the tt_content table and
   # keeps track of the sorting order, which was specified in
   # the backend.
   orderBy = sorting

   # Only select content from column "0" (the column called
   # "normal") and quote the database identifier (column name)
   # "colPos" (indicated by wrapping with {#})
   where = {#colPos}=0
}
```

or `page.10 < styles.content.get`

Comment: Thank you! Got it working with this. Did not know how to reference the content.

Answer (score 3):

What you got is an example where you can verify that your server is working. Like an apache server gives you the information, that you have reached the server.

you need a rendering which loads database content and computes it into a web page.
that could be pure typoscript, but the usual way today is a Fluid-template with rendering information for all content elements.

Either you use an extension package which supports you with everything or you build it by your own.
A start may be this page from the [sitepackage tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/11.5/en-us/MinimalExample/Index.html)

You also can learn from the [introduction package](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/11.5/en-us/IntroductionPackage/Index.html)

in general: [learn FLUID](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Fluid/Introduction.html)